# Swift 5 - Error with the password validation regex

Tags: ios, swift, regex, validation

I am making a sign-in/up function on Swift. I am trying to validate a password using regex. The passwords have the following requirements

- At least 7 characters long
- At least one uppercase letter
- At least one number

This is the validation regex I was using: `"^(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[0-9]){7}$"`

And this is my code

```
let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[0-9]){7}$")
```

Whenever I try to log in with a password that meets these requirements (eg. Greatpass13), Xcode gives me an error saying

```
Thread 1: "Can't do regex matching, reason: (Can't open pattern U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX (string Greatpass13, pattern ^(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[0-9]){7}$, case 0, canon 0))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=^.{7,}$)(?=^.*[A-Z].*$)(?=^.*\d.*$).*
```

##### Short Explanation

- `(?=^.{7,}$)` At least 7 characters long
- `(?=^.*[A-Z].*$)` At least one uppercase letter
- `(?=^.*\d.*$)` At least one number
- `.*` Match the string that contains all assertions

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QNgOUq/2)

##### Swift Example

```
let phonePattern = #"(?=^.{7,}$)(?=^.*[A-Z].*$)(?=^.*\d.*$).*"#

func isValid(password: String) -> Bool {
    return password.range(
        of: phonePattern,
        options: .regularExpression
    ) != nil
}

print(isValid(password: "Pass1"))       // false
print(isValid(password: "Pass23word"))  // true
print(isValid(password: "23password"))  // false
print(isValid(password: "Greatpass13")) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add dot before counter 7

```
func isValidPassword() -> Bool {
        let password = self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        let passwordRegx = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{7}$"
        let passwordCheck = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",passwordRegx)
        return passwordCheck.evaluate(with: password)
 }
```

at least one uppercase,

at least one digit

at least one lowercase

min 7 characters total

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated regex based on yours.

```
let passwordRegx = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{7,}$"
let passwordPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",passwordRegx)
```

Also you need to add {7,} at the end otherwise it will only match for 7 characters and not more than that.

You can test your regex at:
https://regex101.com/